# Get output from C to C++/CLI

Tags: c, c++-cli

I have C++/CLI code function update to richTextbox.

```
public:void WriteToRichTextBox(char * outputText)
    {
        String^ result = gcnew String(outputText);
        richTextBox1->Text += result;
    }
```

And in C Code how can i do:

```
void updateString()
{
    char * abc = "example text";
    WriteToRichTextBox(abc);
}
```

Update answer:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ektebyzx.aspx

Comment: Not in any easy or sensible way as that C code is written. Instead, change your C code to *return* a string.

Comment: @crashmstr sure i know, i only give a example.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a function, it will do what it has to do, for example, you wanna do a divider formed by "="
and to not waste time you can create a function:

```
void divider()
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=80; i++){
        printf("=");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and in the main function you call it:

```
int main()
{
     some code;
     divider();
}
```

and you will get onto you terminal a divider long 80.

I hope that's will help you, at least this is what I understood you wanna get.